# How accurately can Vulcans predict when pon farr will happen?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan

Pon farr is the Vulcans’ drive to mate every seven years, traditionally resolved by returning to Vulcan and their mate. How accurately can they predict when it will happen? Do they just know “sometime this year it will happen” or can they realize “it will happen in exactly five weeks from now, so I’d better request shore leave”?

Obviously Spock is a special case because he is half-Vulcan and expected to avoid it completely; I am interested in full-blooded Vulcans.